# Simple SQL query on highest ID

Tags: java, reactjs, postgresql, axios, derived

I unsuccessfully attempted to leverage Java's DerivedQueries but cannot accomplish the required result so I have to manually write a SELECT Statement.

I want to display one single record in my UI. This should be the most recently generated record (which means it has the highest ID Number) associated with a category that we call "ASMS". In other words, look through all the rows that have ASMS#123, find the one that has the highest ID and then return the contents of one column cell.

ASMS: Entries are classified by 11 specific ASMS numbers.
ID: AutoGenerated
PPRECORD: New entries being inserted each day

I hope the image makes more sense.

```java
//RETURN ONLY THE LATEST RECORD
//https://besterdev-api.apps.pcfepg3mi.gm.com/api/v1/pprecords/latest/{asmsnumber}
@RequestMapping("/pprecords/latest/{asmsNumber}")
public List<Optional<PriorityProgressEntity>> getLatestRecord(@PathVariable(value = "asmsNumber") String asmsNumber) {
    List<Optional<PriorityProgressEntity>> asms_number = priorityprogressrepo.findFirst1ByAsmsNumber(asmsNumber);
    return asms_number;}
```

The ReactJS FE makes an AXIOS.get and I can retrieve all the records associated with the ASMS, but I do not have the skill to display only JSON object that has the highest ID value. I'm happy to do this in the FE also.

[image: Requirement]

I tried Derived Queries. `.findFirst1ByAsmsNumber(asmsNumber)` does not consider the highest ID number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT pprecord FROM YourTable WHERE id =
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM YourTable WHERE asms = '188660')
```

Explanation:

First line select pprecord, second line select the id

I'll improve the answer if any additional question. Upvotes and acceptions are appreciated~

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 2: (SELECT MAX(id) FROM priorityprogress WHERE asms=188660)
                                                        ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 98

Comment: SORTED. Thank you VERY much. Worked first time. I just had to create a duplicate column that was of type Int to match the ID and sorted :)

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice asms is a text column. Just try the statement above, and you won't need a duplicate column.